# What is the formula to generate a formula which can output any three chosen numbers as the first three terms of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivation-of-formulae

I remember learning how to create a formula of form $a^x + b^y + c^z$ where the variables will create any other set of chosen numbers as the first terms of a sequence. But I don't remember how to do that anymore. How do I?

To generate a sequence like $1, 5, 6,$ or any three chosen numbers, how would I create a formula which outputs those three numbers as the first three terms of the sequence?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will walk you most of the way there, but given that this is a pretty open-ended question, I will ask of you do to the rest.

Basically, for a function to output $n$ desired outputs, you need a formula of $n$ unknown variables over an independent variable (like $x$), then do some algebra to determine what they (the unknowns) need to be.

Suppose, like in your case of $n=3$, we want some function $f(x)$ such that $f(0)=a$, $f(1)=b$, and $f(2)=c$ (where $a,b$ and $c$ are what you want the first three outputs to be). They don't have to be inputs at $0$, $1$, and $2$, so I'm assuming that's what you want; but know that you can make them whatever you want.

Now, we need some arbitrary formula that has three unknowns (let's call them $c_0,c_1$ and $c_2$) over $x$. Not all choices for $f$ will be able to be solved for nicely, so that just takes experience of knowing what generally works and what doesn't. The point, however, is that you do have a choice here. A common choice would be a polynomial $f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$. This choice is nice because it generalizes to any $n$.

Thus, we essentially now have three equations

$$c_0+c_1(0)+c_2(0)^2=a,$$
$$c_0+c_1(1)+c_2(1)^2=b,$$
$$c_0+c_1(2)+c_2(2)^2=c.$$

From here, we have all the information to deduce the function. If you notice, this practically gives us $c_0$, as the first equation simplifies to $c_0=a$. We can use that to solve the next two equations.

Can you go from here?

Remember, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are what we have already chosen $f$ to output, so you will be solving for $c_0$, $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: So c_0 is 1, c_1 is 4 and then ```c_2x^2 + 4x + 1 = 6``` and where x is 2 that would be ```4c_2 + 8 + 1 = 6``` but that gives c_2 = -0.75 which gives 9 in the original formula, not 6. It seems like the third term needs to be something other than c_2x^2.

Comment: I am afraid you must have some error in your calculation then, as I can assure you that this formula is a classic tried-and-true method. What values of $a, b$ and $c$ did you pick to get these values?

Comment: I did have an error. It looks like no real numbers can produce this equation as upon review I'm left with c_2 = sqrt(-2) or i*sqrt(2).